# JavaScript img src based on function variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the src of an image to be based on sky+gatMap()+.jpg
The src is supposed to be sky#.jpg where # is the value of getMap().
I am having trouble with the quotation or something, what am I doing wrong here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<img id='sky' src='sky+mapNum()+.jpg' alt='' />");
  </script>
```

This is a case problem out of a javaxcript book. It doesn't tell me how to do this.

Comment: I am well aware it has to have something to do with quotations, but I couldn't figure out the right combination.

Comment: `document.write("<img id='sky' src='sky"+mapNum()+".jpg' alt='' />");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write("<img id='sky' src='sky"+mapNum()+".jpg' alt='' />");
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have to wait 10 min to say question answered.

Answer (score 4):

```
document.write('<img id="sky" src="sky' + mapNum() + '.jpg" alt="" />');
```

That should do it.  Open/close your quotes as needed.  Use different quotes for literal string quotes and end-of-string-literal quotes, or escape with `\` as needed.

I should also point out that `document.write()` usage is generally discouraged.  Consider manipulating the DOM in some other way.  Also, if you are returning any arbitrary string from `mapNum()`, you may be generating invalid HTML, and may even open up yourself to XSS attacks if that value can come from a request parameter.  You should edit the attribute of an element directly instead, when possible.

Answer (score 1):

`<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<img id='sky' src='sky"+mapNum()+".jpg' alt='' />");
   </script>`

u need to break the string before + plus sign by putting a double qoutation mark and then start it again after the next plus sign.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are included in the string and is being interpreted as HTML and not JavaScript.  Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write("<img id='sky' src='sky" + mapNum() + ".jpg' alt='' />");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

after puting " " quotes it becomes a string it means it will not print any value it will just print as it is written. so you should keep in mind to where to use " " quotes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<img id='sky' src='sky'"+mapNum()+".'jpg' alt='' />");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<img id='sky' src='sky" + mapNum + ".jpg' alt='' />");
</script>
```

mapNum is a variable not a function so no () after it. The book very vague.